# Payable bounty, but no answers

Tags: discussion

I don't mean to advertise [How did 'consideration' shift to signify grounds and the act of deliberation, then inducer of a grant or promise?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/500718/334589), and I don't know how else to ask this, but there being no answer still, I don't want the +50 bounty to expire in 12 hours and go to waste.

Thus how can I alert people who may want to try to earn the bounty?

Answer (score 3):

General suggestions would be to improve the question, show the research, add a bounty etc, which I think you have already tried.

There is unfortunately no other way to attract more attention.

Sometimes, even with a bounty, a question might not grab the attention of many. Your question appears to be an example of this. Even a month and a bounty later, it has only managed to attract 61 views, as of now.

There's only then the possibility of it jumping on to the Hot Network Questions. From my experience, a question does not simply go to HNQ, the HNQ takes the question.

Let's wait.. Maybe the right answerer hasn't seen the question yet.

Comment: Actually, there is another: [share the question to other sites, even the non-SE one!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ViCUN.png). Anyway, questions without answers will never get into HNQ...

Answer (score 2):

There’s a book that might help: Fried, Charles. Contract as Promise: A Theory of Contractual Obligations 1981

But I think the real problem here is that this is a question of changes in legal terminology, and might get more response on the law forum of stackexchange.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question! Well, it might answer the Main question, but it doesn't seem very relevant to "How do I increase exposure?"

Comment: [How did 'consideration' semantically shift to mean 'something given in payment'?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/32340/how-did-consideration-semantically-shift-to-mean-something-given-in-payment) – Law.SE (comment link on the OG question)